# JavaFX MediaPlayer HLS bug

Tags: javafx, https, http-live-streaming

Looks like after supporting https for JavaFX media player (HLS), the developers introduced a bug http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u/rt/rev/89ec0be39541

Is there a way to patch my system with that fix? I already downloaded latest JDK and the fix is not there yet !

No answers ! how can someone rely on JavaFX as a media platform if a simple bug prevents HLS from being served? This is why people going C# better release management, patching, faster bug fixes...

Comment: you mean this  if (!URI.startsWith("http://") && !URI.startsWith("https://")) {
                 baseURI = playlistURI.substring(0, playlistURI.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
             }
             needBaseURI = false;

Comment: Exactly ! I debugged the player and it sending http calls like : /api/hls/ http: // webvideoaddress.com  so it is prefixing relative path and then the http absolute path of segments...